# sorting file names ascending where names have a dash in bash

Tags: macos, bash

I have a list of files in a folder.

The names are:

```
1-a
100-a
2-b
20-b
3-x
```

and I want to sort them like

```
1-a
2-b
3-x
20-b
100-a
```

The files are always a number, followed by a dash, followed by anything.

I tried a `ls` with a `col` and `sort` and it works, but I wanted to know if there's a simpler solution.

Forgot to mention: This is bash running on a Mac OS X.

Comment: On Linux (or with GNU `ls`), use `ls -v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort` to define the fields.

```
sort -s -t- -k1,1n -k2 filenames.txt
```

The `-t` tells `sort` to treat `-` as the field separator in input items. `-k1,1n` instructs `sort` to first sort on the first field numerically; `-k2` sorts using the remaining fields as the second key in cade the first fields are equal. `-s` keeps the sort stable (although you could omit it since the entire input string is being used in one field or another).

(Note: I'm assuming the file names do not contain newlines, so that something like `ls > filenames.txt` is guaranteed to produce a file with one name per line. You could also use `ls | sort ...` in that case.)

Comment: I didn't want to save the files to a filenames.txt, so instead I used `ls | sort -s -t- -k1,1n -k2`, which is what you said. So I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some *ls* implementations, *GNU coreutils' ls* is one of them, support the *-v*  (natural sort of (version) numbers within text) option:

```
% ls -v
1-a  2-b  3-x  20-b  100-a
```

or:

```
% ls -v1
1-a
2-b
3-x
20-b
100-a
```

Comment: The stock `ls` with Mac OS X is not one of those implementations.

Comment: Interestingly, even though the synopsis in `man ls` on Mac doesn't list a `-v` option, the detailed description of the options does list **`-v`** _Force unedited printing of non-printable characters. This is the default when the output is not a terminal_.  This is, however, wholly unrelated to the (equally non-standard) `-v` option in GNU `ls`.  There isn't a comparable option documented on Mac.

Comment: I tried it on my Mac and it didn't work. It would've been simpler if I had the `-v` option :(